# Usando uma tabela existente com o AdonisJS

Tags: javascript, adonisjs

Sou iniciante com o framework AdonisJS e preciso utilizar ele em uma tabela já existente com dados. Pesquisando encontrei que deveria criar um Model para a tabela, porém não funcionou e não consegui encontrar uma maneira que funcionasse.
Tenho um cenário similar ao abaixo:
Uma tabela chamada `empresas_clientes` em um banco Postgres com a seguinte estrutura:

```
create table empresas_clientes(
    codigo serial not null primary key,
    razao varchar(50) not null
);
```

E criei um model chamado `Cliente` com o comando `adonis make:model cliente` com a seguinte estrutura:

```
'use strict'

/** @type {typeof import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Lucid/Model')} */
const Model = use('Model')

class Cliente extends Model {

    static get table() {
        return 'empresas_clientes'
    }

    static get primaryKey() {
        return 'codigo'
    }

    static get createdAtColumn() {
        return null
    }

    static get updatedAtColumn() {
        return null
    }
}

module.exports = Cliente
```

Tenho também o controller:

```
'use strict'

const Cliente = require('../../Models/Cliente')

class ClienteController {

    async index({ request }) {
        const cliente = await Cliente.first()
        return cliente
    }
}

module.exports = ClienteController
```

E a seguinte rota:

```
Route.get('/clientes', 'ClienteController.index')
```

Porém quando acesso `/clientes` recebo uma mensagem de erro
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não consegui resolver este problema a e fazer a rota retornar o JSON dos clientes, acredito que seja algum problema em decorrência de estar utilizando uma tabela já existente.

Comment: Qual a versão do Adonisjs?

Comment: É a versão 4.1.0

Answer (score 1):

O seu código está quase certo, você só precisa corrigir uma coisa, no seu controller na função Index vc está chamando o First de forma errada o certo seria:

```
Const cliente = await Cliente.query().first()
```

E vc pode remover esses métodos staticos que você montou dentro do model deixa ele igual ao que ele era quando vc criou ele.